# How to post nested JSON object with Axios?

Tags: javascript, axios

I'm building a React app that interacts with a Wordpress installation through the Wordpress REST API. Right now I'm trying to create a form where a user can update their personal information: when the form is submitted, I invoke the following action, which receives the form data and sends a POST request:

```
export const updateUserInfo = ( userInfo ) => async ( dispatch, getState, api ) => {

    // userInfo looks like this:
    // {
    //     "firstname": "John",
    //     "lastname": "Doe"
    // }

    const userID = getState().currentUser.ID.data; 

    const postUserInfo = {
        "personal_info": userInfo
    }

    const requestAuth = {
        'headers': {
            'Content-type': 'application/json', 
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + cookies.get( 'userToken' )
        }
    }

    await api.post( '/wp-json/wp/v2/users/' + userID, postUserInfo, requestAuth ); 

}
```

The POST request is successful (200 code), and the payload looks correct as well:

```
{
    "personal_info": {
        "firstname": "John", 
        "lastname": "Doe", 
    }
}
```

but the sad truth is the user's info does not get updated, so the values "John" and "Doe" are never really posted...

I have similar requests working when the received `userInfo` is not an object but a simple value, which is what leads me to think the problem is with the nested object.

Comment: have you tried to put firstname and lastname outside of personal_info object?